# How can I start running server in one yml job and tests in another when run server job is still running

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines

So I have 2 yml pipelines currently... one starts running the server and after server is up and running I start the other pipeline that runs tests in one job and once that's completed starts a job that shuts down the server from first pipeline.

I'm kinda new to yml and wondering if there is a way to run all this in a single pipeline...
The problem I came across is that if I put server to run in a first job I do not know how to condition the second job to kick off after server is running. This job doesn't have succeeded of failed condition because it's still in progress as the server has to run in order for tests to be run.

I tried adding a variable that I set to true after server is running but it still never jumps to the next job?

I looked into templates too but those are not very clear to me so any suggestion or documentation or tutorial would be very helpful on how to achive putting this in one pipeline...

I already googled a bunch and will keep googling but figured someone here might have an answer already.

Answer (score 0):

Each agent can run only one job at a time. To run multiple jobs in parallel you must configure multiple agents. You also need sufficient [parallel jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops).

You can specify the conditions under which each job runs. **By default, a job runs if it does not depend on any other job, or if all of the jobs that it depends on have completed and succeeded.** You can customize this behavior by forcing a job to run even if a previous job fails or by specifying a custom condition.

Since you have added a variable that you set to true after server is running. Then try to enable a custom condition, set that job run if a variable is xxx.

More details please kindly check official doc here:

- [Specify jobs in your pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#conditions)
- [Specify conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#enable-a-custom-condition)